# app crashing after taking 3rd picture - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, camera

I have a view in which there are 6 image views. I set the images using camera UIImagePickerController. Everytime I picked the 3rd image, my app always crash and when I checked the Instruments, there are no leaks. What wrong?
Here's my code:

```
- (void)openCamera
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.0001f);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"headOffice"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgHeadOffice"];
        //_imgHeadOffice = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewHeadOffice.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"siteOffice"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgSiteOffice"];
        //_imgSiteOffice = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewSiteOffice.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"roadCondition"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgRoadCondition"];
        //_imgRoadCondition = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewRoadCondition.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"vehicle"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgVehicle"];
        //_imgVehicle = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewVehicle.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"installedTire"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgInstalledTire"];
        //_imgInstalledTire = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewInstalledTire.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else if ([_selectedButton isEqualToString:@"tireScrap"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imgTireScrap"];
        //_imgTireScrap = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        _imgViewTireScrap.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}
```

Here's my Instruments snapshot:
[image: Instrument's snapshot]

EDIT:
the app crashes upon processing line

```
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.0001f);
```

the 3rd time i take a picture. 
this is the log when the app closes
[image: log snapshot]

Comment: Are those images the same? May be they have big sizes and your app wants to allocate a huge buffer, so ios kills it

Comment: please provide stack trace also, after putting exception break point

Comment: no, they aren't the same. i have resized it to 0.0001f quality (see my code)

Comment: when you are working with simulator there is no such issues. Enable zombie objects in edit scheme you can figure out which object causes the crash

Comment: there are no stack trace. it just closes. no error whatsoever..

Comment: Not with instruments. run it normally without instruments and check whether its getting crashed

Comment: yeah, i did that originally. i just found out about instruments an hour ago. i just posted the log snapshot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26919/discussion-between-rafeek-and-ykmlo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently downsampling the image still makes it around 200 kb in size.
after downsampling, i rescale it to 37.5% and it works just fine. thx all